# How to call an object in an array's methods?

Tags: java, arrays, object, methods

I have created a class called `Tilecreator`. Within this class, there is the method `GenerateTile()`, which applies some values to the object.

If I have created an array of these objects, how can I apply values to them in a loop?

For example, I tried:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    createdTile[] tile[i] = new Tilecreator();
    tile[i].GenerateTile(
}
```

Comment: Did you initialize the array before the loop? What do you mean by "createdTile[] tile[i]"?

Answer (score 0):

```
Tile[] tiles = new Tile[100];
```

If you want to loop through an array and check if theres any empty spots to initialize:

```
for(int id = 0; id < tiles.length; id++) //loops through entire array starting at tiles[0]
     if(tiles[id] == null) { //checks if spot in array is available
         tiles[id] = value; //= new Tile(); initializes value for reference in array
         tiles[id].method(); //calls method from initialized reference
     }
```

If you don't care about empty spots, take out the `if(tiles[id] == null)`

If you just want to loop through an array that already has values, and want to trigger methods

```
for(Tile tile : tiles) 
    tile.method()
```

To initialize array spots, you MUST use the first forloop I showed (basic forloop). Enhanced forloops (second loop example) uses a copy of the value in the array, rather than the actual reference itself, so you can't initialize using that copy

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming there is something like this before the loop:

```
Tile[] tile = new Tile[10];
```

If the GenerateTile method is static, and the method accepts a tile object, you can do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
 tile[i] = new Tile(); // or another constructor
 tile[i] = Tilecreator.GenerateTile(tile[i]);
}
```

If you have an array of Tilecreator objects (which I think is the case, given your statement "If I have created an array of these objects..."):

```
Tilecreator[] tile = new Tilecreator[10];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
 tile[i] = new Tilecreator(); // or another constructor
 tile[i].GenerateTile();
}
```

If that is the case, I would rename Tilecreator to Tile, and have a separate Tilecreator class handle the creation of tile arrays.